# Why can't TeXlive 2017 compile what MiKTeX 2.9 correctly compiles?

Tags: texlive

I have a paper, using `spieman` class, which is about to be uploaded on a journal's webpage. Then, their server compiles the file(s) to generate a merged PDF.

Take the following example into account (I intentionally copy the whole preamble because the problem may be somehow related to that):

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hang,flushmargin}{footmisc}

\documentclass[12pt]{spieman} 

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\let\openbox\relax

\usepackage[right=2.5cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} 

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\def\stackalignment{c}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argA}{arg}

\makeatletter
\def\thmheadbrackets#1#2#3{%
    \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
    \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont[#3]}}}
\makeatother

\newtheoremstyle{brakets}% Name
{}% space above
{}% space below
{\itshape}% body font
{}% indent
{\bfseries}% head font
{.}% punctuation after head
{ }% space after head (has to be space or dimension!)
{\thmheadbrackets{#1}{#2}{#3}}% head spec

\newtheoremstyle{defbrakets}% Name
{}% space above
{}% space below
{\normalfont}% body font
{}% indent
{\bfseries}% head font
{.}% punctuation after head
{ }% space after head (has to be space or dimension!)
{\thmheadbrackets{#1}{#2}{#3}}% head spec

\newtheoremstyle{defproblem}% Name
{}% space above
{}% space below
{\normalfont}% body font
{}% indent
{\bfseries}% head font
{.}% punctuation after head
{ }% space after head (has to be space or dimension!)
{\thmheadbrackets{#1}{#2}{#3}}% head spec

\theoremstyle{brakets}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\theoremstyle{defbrakets}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem{plm}{Problem}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    hidealllines=true,
    leftline=true,
    innerleftmargin=10pt,
    innerrightmargin=10pt,
    innertopmargin=0pt,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=mystyle]{proof}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pzc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}{<-> s * [1.10] pzcmi7t}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\newcommand{\z}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\title{This is some Title\footnote{This work was financially supported by grant number 111 and the MMM agreement number eee.}}

\author[a,*]{John Ryan Doe}
\author[b]{Brian Edward Henderson}
\affil[a]{School of Engineering, University of Sussex, UK}
\affil[b]{School of Cybernetics, Technical University of Munich, Germany}

\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}
\cftpagenumbersoff{table} 

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\keywords{a}

{\noindent \footnotesize\textbf{*}Corresponding author: \linkable{a@b.c}}

\end{document}
```

When I compile the code above on my Windows 10 using MiKTeX 2.9 (particularly XeLaTeX), everything is fine:

[image]

But when I upload the code to the journal's webpage, the compilation result is problematic, say, a first page includes:

[image]

and the other one reads:

[image]

The log file says the server uses Texlive 2017, but I can't understand why this [log file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=25271750723107018401) returns these 3 errors, while the MikTeX is pretty fine with it.

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.121 \author[a
               ,*]{x}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing    to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X   to quit.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.123 \affil
            [a]{X}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.124 \affil
            [b]{Y}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: It's very likely because of different package/class versions on the two systems. You could put `\listfiles` at the very top of your document and compare the version numbers listed in the .log file. In this specific case the difference seems to be in the `\author` command, where one version accepts an optional argument and the other doesn't.

Comment: probably unrelated to the errors but the document is written for pdflatex and should not be run with xelatex